# Como retornar substrings em uma string delimitada por delimitadores?

Tags: php

O meu problema é seguinte: Eu tenho uma string `"Olá [eu] sou uma [string]"`, como eu faria para retornar as substrings que estão dentro dos delimitadores `"["` e `"]"`?

*Quando eu falo retornar, estou querendo dizer um array como o da função explode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode usar um expressão regular para casa o texto dentro dos colchetes com a função `preg_match_all()`. Como o que importa está dentro de um grupo você deve acessar o array retornado no indice `1` e depois pode fazer um foreach para acessar todos os textos capturados. Ex `echo $m[1][0]`

```
$str= "Olá [eu] sou uma [string]";
$regex = '#\[([\w\s]+)\]#';

preg_match_all($regex, $str, $m);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($m);
```

Saída:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [eu]
            [1] => [string]
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => eu
            [1] => string
        )

)
```